# Как последовательно использовать onReplyToMessage в JS Node-Telegram-Bot-Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-telegram-bot-api

Хочу сделать так, что бы пользователь мог указать id канала => указать сообщение и отправить по этому id и написать содержание сообщения. Помогите мне, пожалуйста, осуществить это.

```js
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const bot = new TelegramBot('XXXXXXXXXXXXX', {polling: true});

  bot.onText(/\/ot/, async(msg) => {
let listenerReply;
let contentMessage = await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Укажите ID канала", {"reply_markup": {"force_reply": true}});
listenerReply = (async (replyHandler) => {
    bot.removeReplyListener(listenerReply);
    let contentMessage = await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `ID кананала: ${replyHandler.text}\nУкажите содержимое ответа`, {"reply_markup": {"force_reply": true}
        
    });
   id = replyHandler.text
});
bot.onReplyToMessage(contentMessage.chat.id, contentMessage.message_id, listenerReply);
listenerReply2 = (async (replyHandler1) => {
    bot.removeReplyListener(listenerReply);
    let contentMessage2 = await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Ответ успешно отправлен`, {
        'reply_markup': {'force_reply': false} 
    })
    text = replyHandler1.text
    })
    bot.onReplyToMessage(contentMessage.chat.id, contentMessage.message_id, listenerReply);
    bot.sendMessage(id, text)
})
```